# How to create a GUI from DTD?

Tags: python, xml, user-interface, dtd

I have xml configs which are very complex. They are validated using dtds. I am looking for some application which reads the dtds and provides a GUI interface to write xmls. So that we don't have to write xmls by hand. If there is nothing existing already, how to start with developing one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you try [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/)?
You can edit XML files according to the DTD.

If your audience is not development oriented, you can have a look to [Editix XML Editor](http://www.editix.com/) (the free version is already fully usable) or [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) (a strange mix between the classic windows notepad and eclipse ;) ).

Otherwise, if you want to write come code, have a look to [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/) there are some widgets to edit/view HTML and XML.

Comment: yes. I have tried but the GUI is not intended for programmers. So cannot expect them to run Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [oXygen XML Author](http://www.oxygenxml.com/xml_author.html). It's not intended for programmers/developers like oXygen XML Editor is. It's a WYSIWYG XML authoring tool. You can create CSS stylesheets to display the XML in a way that is easy for the authors to create/modify the XML.

It's not free and you'll have to create CSS for display, but it is *much* better than trying to develop something from scratch. It also supports creating templates so that authors can start with a base XML file and then modify/update.